# Qt - Esc should not close the dialog

Tags: c++, qt, dialog, escaping

How to make <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to minimize a dialog? By default it closes. Should I process `KeyEvent` or there is a better way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you may use this:

```
void MyDialog::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e) {
    if(e->key() != Qt::Key_Escape)
        QDialog::keyPressEvent(e);
    else {/* minimize */}
}
```

Also have a look at [Events and Event Filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/eventsandfilters.html) docs.

Answer (score 19):

Escape calls reject(). I override this function (in my case not to minimize the dialog but to prompt to save)

```
void MyDialog::reject() {if(cleanupIsOK()) done(0);}
```

Al_

Answer (score 5):

Renaming the reject is correct. But be careful because if you want to close the dialog in other way you cannot call close.

```
MyDialog::reject(){
    if(some_closing_condition)
    {
        QDialog::reject() //calls the default close.
    }
    else
    {
        //skip reject operation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly Qt docs state ESC calls reject()

> Escape Key
>
> If the user presses the Esc key in a dialog, QDialog::reject() will be
> called. This will cause the window to close: The close event cannot be
> ignored

yet QDialog::reject() documentation says hides. i.e closeEvent() is **not** called, which I have confirmed to be the case.

> void QDialog::reject()
> Hides the modal dialog and sets the result code to Rejected

Comment: My code relied on `closeEvent()` being called, and it worked with Qt 5, but broke with Qt 6. Yes, with Qt 6 what you've described is right, `reject()` calls `hide()`, and `closeEvent()` is not called.

Answer (score 0):

I think that to do this, you would basically have to avoid inheriting from `QDialog`. [The documentation for `QDialog`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qdialog.html) says:

> **Escape Key**
>
> If the user presses the Esc key in a
>   dialog, QDialog::reject() will be
>   called. This will cause the window to
>   close: The close event cannot be
>   ignored.

Comment: nice docs Tyler! why not override instead of avoid inheriting though?